# What should I do with my daffodil bulbs after having removed them?

Tags: bulbs, planting-times, storage, daffodils

I've recently dug up a patch of the garden and taken out a whole bunch of daffodil bulbs. I want to keep these bulbs, so what should I do with them now that I have dug them up?

Would I be better planting them now or storing them and planting them at a more suitable time? If I should store them, what's the best way to store the bulbs?

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to store them is to put them in the ground. However, if for some reason, you can't plant them again, wash them thoroughly, keep them in a well ventilated area for a week or so, and then put them in paper or cloth bags.

Write the date on a label in case you forget when you dug them up.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the answer by @Alina...

Store in a cool dark place.

Comment: Maybe this answer should just be a comment on @Alina's answer